# How to retrieve getUpdated or getNotebookGuid information in evernote api

Tags: android, evernote

In android, with SearchNotes.java example and a very simple add from me:

```
Log.d("something", title + " "+ note.getUpdated() + " "+ note.getNotebookGuid());
```

Api returns only 0 or null! Did I missed something?

More details of the context of the code:

```
try{
            mEvernoteSession.getClientFactory().createNoteStoreClient()
                    .findNotesMetadata(filter, offset, pageSize, spec, new OnClientCallback<NotesMetadataList>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(NotesMetadataList data) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.notes_searched, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            removeDialog(DIALOG_PROGRESS);
                            for(NoteMetadata note : data.getNotes()) {
                                String title = note.getTitle();
                                notesNames.add(title);
                                Log.d("something", title + " "+ note.getUpdated() + " "+ note.getNotebookGuid());
                            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `NoteStore#findNotesMetadata`, you can specify what it returns with `NotesMetadetaResultSpec`.
http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_findNotesMetadata
http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/reference/NoteStore.html#Struct_NotesMetadataResultSpec

Make sure you set `includeUpdated` and `includeNotebookGuid` to `true`.